# Specify more than one rule in ValueInjecter's ConventionInjection(s)

Tags: c#, .net, valueinjecter

I'm new to ValueInjecter. I knew how to match properties with the same name but different caps:

```
public class IgnoreCaseInjection : ConventionInjection
{
     protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
     {
         return String.Compare(c.SourceProp.Name, c.TargetProp.Name, 
                               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
     }
}
```

And:

```
var foo = new Foo() { ID = 1};
var bar = new Bar();
bar.InjectFrom<IgnoreCaseInjection>(foo);
```

This will map `foo.ID` to `bar.Id`. What if I have another properties that are mapped using different rule? For example, I also have `foo.MyProp` (which is an enumerable of type `FooEnum`) that I want to map to `bar.MyProp` which is a string (I mean it to store the `.ToString()` representation of the enum).

How can I add another rule to my converter? How will the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I only found the solution in [ValueInjecter's documentation](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation):

```
viewModel.InjectFrom(entity)
                .InjectFrom<CountryToLookup>(entity)
                .InjectFrom<AnythingElseYouMightImagine>(entity)
                .InjectFrom(new StuffInjection(stuffRepository), anotherEntity);
```

And you have to code each of the classes and make sure they don't overlap

Answer (score 0):

you can alwas use || && to add additional rules in the Match method, but in this specific case I would create another injection like here:

https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Useful%20injections&referringTitle=Home

in this page ^ you can see EnumToInt and IntToEnum, you can modify it and do the EnumToStr